# React-Native: Get dimensions of props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a Library for React-Native and I have an unusual  requirement. I don't know If its possible or not.

I have to build a wrapper component, Lets say

```
<Container showContent={true}>
  <Text>hello</Text>
</Container>
```

And inside Container, It would be like this

```
render() {
  <View>
    {this.props.children}
  </View>
}
```

The problem is, this would be a conditional render. I know I can get the Dimensions of children by just using the parent `<View>`component inside the container component.

But I can't, Why? Because I want to measure it without rendering. 
It would be like

```
render() {
  if(this.props.showContent) {
    return this.props.children;
  }
  return <SomeOtherView />
}
```

And initially It would be `SomeOtherView` and during that phase, I need the height and width of the children components.
I don't want to pass methods and all, as I am building a library. So I want an elegant way. I just want the user to use my component like it is included in first code snippet and inside component I should get the height and width of children even without rendering it.

I don't know if it's possible or not. 
I tried to see all the methods provided by `props.children`, but can't find any which I can use.

Comment: Have you tried this.props.children.length?

Comment: It will just give the number of children inside my container, I want the height and width

Comment: Ahhh I see, I misunderstood then. It would assume that the children are rendered before you can height/width, which you don't really want.

Comment: Yes exactly, after they render. I can calculate it using .measure, but i need the dimensions before render. or any approach will do.

Comment: If I understand correctly you will use the width / height of `this.props.children` on `<SomeOtherView />`?

Comment: @Siavas correct

Comment: You can try adding onLayout property inside the root view, however, an undesired effect is that while you are measuring the size, the view is gonna be rendered ... sadly react-native collapsible uses this method, it's impossible to know the real size without rendering or having it defined

Comment: @ValdaXD sadly I can't use that approach here, as my app would crash. I need to block the render somehow.

Comment: Mmm i don't think it's possible, however you can try looking ath the source code of react native collapsible to check if there is a workaround with onLayout https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/blob/master/Collapsible.js

Comment: I made style prop required in the child component, and then copied those style properties, temporary fix though

Comment: Well, can you elaborate as to why your app would crash if you rendered `children` (say momentarily)? I may have a solution in mind.